# como recorrer array dentro de otro array?

Tags: javascript

hola tengo un problema con la propiedad for cuando son dos bucles, uno lo recorro bien y muestro los datos, pero cuando quiero recorrer otro array dentro del primero no puedo hacerlo, utilizo la sintaxis for( algo of array) pero al hacer otro for dentro de ese array me sale error,
mi codigo javascript:

```
       // recorrer telefono para mostrarlos todos
     for(cuit of response.data.result){
       for(telefono of cuit){
        this.telefonoAInsertar = {  telefono: telefono.sucEmpresa.sucTelefonos }
        this.telefonoArrayTab2Cuit.push(telefono.telefono.nroTlefono)
        this.contenidoTelefono.push(this.telefonoAInsertar)
        console.log(telefono)
       }
         }
```

el array principal es =>`for(cuit of response.data.result){  }`
el segundo array seria para mostrar teléfonos dentro del primer array que es donde no se como escribirlo

```
        this.telefonoAInsertar = {  telefono: telefono.sucEmpresa.sucTelefonos }
        this.telefonoArrayTab2Cuit.push(telefono.telefono.nroTlefono)
        this.contenidoTelefono.push(this.telefonoAInsertar)
        console.log(telefono)
       }
```

Comment: *me sale error*. ¿Puedes copiar y pegar el error que te sale?

Comment: Considera añadir a la pregunta un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable que comprenda tanto el código JavaScript como un trozo de lo que contiene `response.data.result`

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el array que quieres iterar? Así podríamos replicar tu código y  a lo mejor ayudarte con otras maneras de conseguir el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 1):

podes simplemente recorrer el array "padre" con forEach y luego, dentro del ciclo, recorrer cada uno de los hijos.

```js
let arreglo1 = []
let arreglo2 = [1,2,3]
let arreglo3 = ["a","b","c"]

arreglo1.push(arreglo2)
arreglo1.push(arreglo3)

arreglo1.forEach(contenido => contenido.forEach(dentro => console.log(dentro)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recorrerlo con el .map()

```js
let arregloPadre = [1,2,3]
let arregloHijo = ["a","b","c"]

arregloPadre.map((padre) => {
  console.log(padre)
  arregloHijo.map((hijo) => {
    console.log(hijo)
    })
})
```

Comment: Map es para hacer transformaciones, es mejor usar forEach para simplemente recorrer el array